# PFC power GND vs signal GND

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, grounding

I'm designing a full-bridge totem-pole PFC that I'm controlling with a DSP. It's an non-isolated topology, but I have 2 grounds: power P_GND and signal S_GND, which are connected at a single point using a ferrite bead. P_GND is the source of the bottom FETs in the full bridge.

I don't have any issue with the isolated sensors and drivers, since I can connect each side of the isolation to each ground. However, I'm not sure which ground I should use for the non-isolated sensors and drivers.

[image: Link to schematic: https://i.imgur.com/TTTuccD.png]

Is this approach with the two grounds and the ferrite okay, or should I just have one common ground and keep noisy areas as separated as possible in the layout?

Comment: Is there some reason you must have S_GND isolated (in some way other than a direct connection) to P_GND?

Comment: @TimWilliams There's no reason they need to be isolated. I just started with two grounds to avoid switching noise to pass from P_GND to S_GND

Comment: @Marcos Never ever split ground unless your doing analog audio systems or galvanic isolation. Layout your board with solid ground layers (L2,L3 on a four layer) and stitch the planes together. You wont have issues with ground noise. You will however have if you split ground. Seperate your high current devices from you DSP/ADC etc. by 10mm or so. The gate drivers belong to the high current section. Dont route low-voltage signals through this section. Think about your component placement for 3/4 of the time and about routing 1/4.

Comment: Putting a resistance between the grounds means that current becomes a voltage difference between the grounds. Rather than isolating switching noise this is likely to make it much worse if anything connected to the signal ground uses the power supply output.

Comment: Besides grounding, I recommend you pay attention to the parasitic capacitance primary-secondary of the floating isolated dc-dc converters. It must be around a few pF otherwise common-mode noise will bring difficulties. I describe the TPPFC in my [tutorial](http://powersimtof.com/Downloads/PPTs/Introduction%20to%20PFC.pdf) on power factor correction if you have interest in the subject.

Answer (score 1):

My best advice might seem at first contrary to the current route you are taking. It's this: use an isolated driver circuit on the low-side as well as the high-side. If you do this then there is no question about how to connect power and signal grounds.

Your question makes me think like it's a circuit in development so, it isn't a cost-issue to take this route.

Once you are happy that things works fine you can experiment with a galvanic connection between PGND and SGND (knowing that the circuit has been proven with a fully-isolated drive for both MOSFETs). Make a single connection between the two grounds and choose the spot carefully. Then, you can consider replacing the isolated supply on the low-side with a non-isolated type.

You won't need a ferrite.

And take note what Verbal Kint says in his comment; use isolated drivers with low isolation capacitance (this includes the isolated DC converters). Both Recom and Murata make isolated DC converters that have around 3 pF isolation capacitance and a barrier transient rating of many tens of kV/μs. These will be needed especially on the high-side.

Another advantage of keeping both low-side and high-side isolated is that you can largely forget about different delay times between top and bottom driver circuits (meaning shoot-through won't be a big issue to consider).

So, short story is use isolated drive circuits for both then consider bypassing the lower side (if really needed).

Comment: Based on the idea here, I would go one step further: Also isolate the output voltage measurement. What then happens, is that your control circuit becomes fully isolated from mains, so one could tie it to PE, or any other convenient potential.

Comment: @tobalt I expect that the standard method of using a TL431 circuit and an opto-isolator would suffice (used on many, many flyback designs for roughly the same purpose). Current monitoring (if needed) can be done with isolated hall-effect devices.